# WPF Binding - Self Binding with its own DataContext

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Anyone got a situation to bind the same `DataContext` to Text property (for example) in TextBlock.

I have to assign the `DataContext` to reflect some trigger based on the Data values from Datacontext in my style. at the same time, i need to bind with the same DataContext object to get the Text Property After applying some conversion on either `IValueConverter/IMultivalueConverter`.

As i know `{Binding}`, just bind with the current datacontext. But in the same scenario how to use converter with it? 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DataEntryTextBlock1}" Grid.Row="1"
               DataContext="{Binding MyField1}"
               Text="{Binding MyField1, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}">
    </TextBlock>
```

This XAML script does not work, as the Text binding is trying to look for the MyField1 variable inside the MyField1.

Thanks,
Vinodh

Comment: DataContext="{Binding MyField1}" implies that you've already set DataContext on an higher element. If you set context on the <Window>, for example, it is known by the child elements without having to specify it again within each of them.

Answer (score 8):

`{Binding}` is equivalent to `{Binding Path=.}` so in you case you can use

```
Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"
```

[`Binding.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN

> Optionally, a period (.) path can be used to bind to the current source. For example, Text="{Binding}" is equivalent to Text="{Binding Path=.}"